# How to find out a correct string in String arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm studying java by myself and trying to write a single program but I'm getting stuck and I assume it's in if-statements. When I input the correct string it shows: "ID not found". Anyone could fix it or guide me how to improve it?

> Program description: There is an array containing of some strings. It
> asks a user to input a string and then the program should check if the
> input of the user is in that array if "yes" it should print: "ID
> found", if not: "ID not found" and keep looping until one of those
> ID-s is not found by the user.

```
public class CatchYourLuck {
    
    private static Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input your id: ");
        String[] ids = {"S0362673", "S0362674", "S0362675", "S0362676" +
                        "S0362677", "S0362701", "S0362702", "S0362703" +
                        "S0362704", "S0362705", "S0362737", "S0362738" +
                        "S0362739", "S0362740", "S0362741", "S0362751" +
                        "S0362752", "S0362753", "S0362754", "S0362760" +
                        "S0362761", "S0362769", "S0362770", "S0362771" +
                        "S0362772", "S0362773", "S0362778", "S0362779" +
                        "S0362780", "S0362781", "S0362782", "S0362799" +
                        "S0362800", "S0362801", "S0362802", "S0362803" +
                        "S0362820", "S0362821", "S0362822", "S0362823" +
                        "S0362824", "S0362839", "S0362840", "S0362841" +
                        "S0362842", "S0362845", "S0362846", "S0362850" +
                        "S0362851", "S0362855", "S0307665", "S0307666" +
                        "S0307667", "S0307668", "S0307669", "S0307670" +
                        "S0307671", "S0307672", "S0307673", "S0307674" +
                        "S0307675", "S0307676", "S0307677", "S0307678" +
                        "S0307679", "S0307680", "S0307681", "S0307682" +
                        "S0307683", "S0307684", "S0307685", "S0307686" +
                        "S0307687", "S0307688"
        };

        String luckyId = scanner.nextLine();
        while(true){
            for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
                System.out.println(ids[i]);
                if(luckyId.equals(ids[i])){
                    System.out.println("\"ID found\"");
                    break;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("\"ID not found\"");
                    luckyId = scanner.nextLine();
            }
        }
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is executed every time you go through the loop. So after looking at the first value (assuming it's not the one that was entered) you will print "ID not found". You shouldn't be coming to the conclusion until **after** the loop. In other words: you can know if you *found* it inside the loop, but you can only be sure that you *did not find it* once the loop has finished.

Comment: Are you aware you are using a + instead of a , in your list of ids on the end? This looks accidental.

Comment: You are concatenating some strings with the plus sign at the end of the line. Use comma there, same as between other ids. Now there are some entries in your array like "S0307686" + "S0307687" so "S0307686S0307687". Do not know, probably too trivial to be kept.

Comment: Joachim has the most immediate problem.  You should probably step through the code with a debugger to see what he is talking about.  The code as written only checks the first element ("0") before printing "not found" and asking for more input.  There's other problems too but that's the main one.

Comment: Joachim Sauer, if I put "if-statement" out of loop it gives an error. could you please give some more description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should break the loop when the ID is found.
2. You can use a boolean variable (e.g. `found` in the code given below) to track if the ID has been found.

**Code:**

```
boolean found;
do {
    found = false;
    System.out.print("Input your id: ");
    String luckyId = scanner.nextLine();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (luckyId.equals(ids[i])) {
            System.out.println("\"ID found\"");
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("\"ID not found\"");
    }
} while (!found);
```

**A sample run:**

```
Input your id: 123
"ID not found"
Input your id: S0307681
"ID found"
```

Comment: I need while looping to scan if the user inputs incorrect id

Comment: @user13738974 - I've posted an update which fulfils this requirement.

Comment: It works as I expected. Thanks to all of you friends for sharing your helps and knowledges.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code needs exact input (without an space allowance and with the exact case):-

**We can do the following instead:-**

Either we only input the exact input in which case it will work as desired under some simple modifications.

**Or**

We code as the following. You should note that we have used `trim()` and `toUpperCase()`.

```java
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input your id: ");
        String[] ids = { "S0362673", "S0362674", "S0362675", "S0362676" + "S0362677", "S0362701", "S0362702",
                "S0362703" + "S0362704", "S0362705", "S0362737", "S0362738" + "S0362739", "S0362740", "S0362741",
                "S0362751" + "S0362752", "S0362753", "S0362754", "S0362760" + "S0362761", "S0362769", "S0362770",
                "S0362771" + "S0362772", "S0362773", "S0362778", "S0362779" + "S0362780", "S0362781", "S0362782",
                "S0362799" + "S0362800", "S0362801", "S0362802", "S0362803" + "S0362820", "S0362821", "S0362822",
                "S0362823" + "S0362824", "S0362839", "S0362840", "S0362841" + "S0362842", "S0362845", "S0362846",
                "S0362850" + "S0362851", "S0362855", "S0307665", "S0307666" + "S0307667", "S0307668", "S0307669",
                "S0307670" + "S0307671", "S0307672", "S0307673", "S0307674" + "S0307675", "S0307676", "S0307677",
                "S0307678" + "S0307679", "S0307680", "S0307681", "S0307682" + "S0307683", "S0307684", "S0307685",
                "S0307686" + "S0307687", "S0307688" };

        String luckyId = scanner.nextLine();
         OL:while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                if (luckyId.trim().toUpperCase().equals(ids[i])) {
                    System.out.println("\"ID found at ids["+i+"]\"");
                    break OL;
                } 
            }
            System.out.println("\"ID not found\"");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Please note that some ids are concated `"S0362703" + "S0362704"` instead. and we did break the while loop not the for loop. finally not found notification is outside for loop not inside for loop. Not a big difference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should store those entries in an array list instead of an array.
You can then use the `.contains(luckyId)` call to determine if the `luckyId` is in your list.

This obviates the need for the looping and conditional logic you are now using. It is also far clearer to another programmer who might read it.

Comment: This is nice advice but (a) it's not an answer to the question and (b) the logic flaw would have been the same whether using an array or a list.

Comment: Really? `if (condition) break;` is very common, or `if (condition) return x;` or `if (condition) continue;` ... now if I see a _labeled_ break I get sketched. `.contains()` in ArrayList uses `indexOf` internally, which uses `if (condition) return i` itself. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java — so you're really just deferring it to someone else.

Comment: Note the lack of break in my solution and note its simplicity.

Comment: Oh I know @nc and I'd probably do that or `.stream()` IRL — "suspicious" seemed a bit strong to me and, if it's not in your code that break is probably _somewhere_ under the covers in a library.